# OneToMany with Embeddable not working

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am using Spring Boot 1.3.1 with Hibernate 4.3.11 and JPA. I have the following mapping:

```
@Entity
public class Game {
   @EmbeddedId
   private GameId id;

   @Embedded
   private Prize prize;
}

@Embeddable
public class Prize {
   private String name;
   @OneToMany
   @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
   private List<ImageReference> images;
}

@Entity
public class ImageReference {
  @EmbeddedId
  private ImageReferenceId id;
  private ImageType type;
  private ImageFormat format;
}

@Embeddable
public class GameId {
  private UUID id;
}

@Emdeddable
public class ImageReferenceId {
  private UUID id;
}
```

I am using Spring Data JPA to create a repository (extending from `CrudRepository`)

When using this mapping 3 tables are created: `game`, `game_images` and `image_reference`. However, the `game_images` table does not get filled up. There is 1 insert in `game` and 3 inserts in `image_reference` (My test adds 3 items to the 'images' collection). Any idea why this is?

My test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration({Application.class, GameRepositoryTest.TestConfiguration.class})
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.properties")
public class GameRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private GameRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Test
    public void test()
    {
        Game game = repository.save(Games.newRandomGameWithPrizeImages());
        assertThat( game ).isNotNull();

        assertThat(jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM game", Long.class )).isEqualTo(1);
        assertThat(jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM image_reference", Long.class )).isEqualTo(3);
        assertThat(jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM game_images", Long.class )).isEqualTo(3);
    }

    @Configuration
    static class TestConfiguration
    {
        @Bean
        public ImageRepository imageRepository() {
            return new LocalFileSystemImageRepository(new InMemoryUniqueIdGenerator());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code that does the saving and also the code of the embedded IDs. What is the `game_images` table?

Comment: Added code. The `game_images` table contains the association between the game id and the id of the image reference so the database knows what images are part of what game/prize.

Comment: In that case it is the join table - how did you get that name configured? By default, JPA provider will name the join table as `game_image_reference`. Do you have a `@JoinTable` annotation that you are not showing?

Comment: I did not configure the name and there is no @JoinTable annotation. It seems to be the concatenation of `game` with the name of the property of the List of ImageReferences (`images`). If I change that name, the name of the join table also changes.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find in the JPA spec the detailed definition how a relationship in an embeddable class should be mapped to the DB. How it **could** be mapped instead of a join table is the default solution in case of direct entity OneToMany relationship, ie. a foreign key on the Many side. You can achieve that by specifying a `@JoinColumn` in `Prize`

```
@OneToMany
@Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="GAME_ID")
private List<ImageReference> images;
```

or, if you don't want to hide it in `Prize`, use the `@AssociationOverride` in `Game`

```
@Embedded
@AssociationOverride(name= "images", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="GAME_ID"))
private Prize prize;
```

Then, the `game_images` table would be obsolete.

---

Edit:
Hibernate has a bug [HHH-4384](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-4384) that requires you to put a `@JoinColumn` annotation on the relationship in the embeddable class (even without any annotation values) if you want to use `@AssociationOverride`.

Comment: Thanks for this. However, this results in a GAME_ID column in my `image_reference` table which I don't want since ImageReference objects are not only used in Game/Prize objects, but also in other objects. (BTW: The `@AssociationOverride` alternative does not seem to work, it gives `Illegal attempt to define a @JoinColumn with a mappedBy association: prize.images`)

Comment: I added info about the Hibernate bug that causes this exception. I understand your reasoning about preferring to use a joint table. Maybe I'll investigate some more how to fix it.